# What is this error "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "shop.css" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product""?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to extract detail of products entered by that administrator.

Here is the part of code dealing with that:

```
router.get('/admin-product/:userid', (req, res, next)=>{
    
    Product.find({_id: req.params.userid})    
           .then(prods=>{
                res.render('adminproduct', {
                    prods: prods, 
                    userid: req.params.userid, 
                    name:"vinod"
                });
           })
           .catch(err=>{
               console.log(err);
           })
    
    
})
```

But when i execute the code i get error as `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "shop.css" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"`

Guide me on what is causing this problem and how to eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your frontend/client is requesting the `shop.css` styles with the base path `/admin-product`, i.e. `HTTP GET <yourhost>:/admin-product/shop.css`.

Since you've declared `:usedId` as a path parameter the value `shop.css` will be passed to mongoose through `req.params.userid`.

Looks to me like you should either fix this on the client-side or fix serving the static content through `/admin-product`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but all I had to do was to change `href="./shop.css"` to `href="/shop.css"` in the template link.
By doing that the problem was resolved.

Please comment if someone has an explanation for this.

Comment: As @eol already pointed, by doing `href='./shop.css'`, the code will concat your base URL with shop.css and thus, will make a GET on your composed URL. But with `href='/shop.css'`, the code will search a file named "shop.css" standing at the root of the directory. I suggest you consider @eol's comment to fix this as it seems as confusing for you as it is for us.